# End of function return to before function

Tags: javascript, function, dom-manipulation

sorry about this might be weird question with weird title.
i have this function in Javascript:

```
function alfred(){
    document.querySelector('.image-7-panel').classList.toggle('notactive');
    document.querySelector('.image-8-panel').classList.toggle('notactive');
    document.querySelector('.background').classList.toggle('alfred-background');
    var text = document.getElementById("heroes");
    if(text.innerHTML !== "Alfred"){
        text.innerHTML = "Alfred";
    } else {
        text.innerHTML = "Heroes are back";
    }
}
```

but I want that after this is running, it goes back to where it was before running. how can I put this running? This function runs on click and with the same click another one runs. The clearTimeout is not helping me here but can't find a normal solution for this.
 Going to explain with the real example. When I click, shows an image and a name associated. I want that after I click, the image goes back to the one it was before clicking and also the nam

Comment: What do you mean by "goes back to where it was before running"? Running the function again?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the paragraph at the end of the question and elaborate?  What does "goes back to where it was before running" mean?

Comment: also *"the clearTimeout is not helping..."* which `clearTimeout` ?

Comment: There is no `clearTimeout` in the code that you provded. Furthermore, a function call *always* proceeds with the next line after the function call when the function ends (unless an exception occurred).

Comment: Sorry, Going to explain with the real example. When I click, shows an image and a name associated. I want that after I click, the image goes back to the one it was before clicking and also the name

Comment: Explain in the question please, not in comments (you can edit it).

Comment: Please add all explanations to your question (use [Edit]) - do not post them as comments.

Comment: if possible, add a working snippet with an example of the current code running. (use the `<>` button in the toolbar)

Comment: Yes @CalvinNunes there is not. But i just wrote to say that i thought of that but was not helping me

Comment: Trying to interpret here ... You have a thing that is a "panel" or a "card", when you _press the mouse button_ (mousedown) on the panel it changes what is showing; when you _release_ the mouse button (mouseup) it returns to what it was showing before. (Note that pressing the mouse button is not a "click" ... it is only half of a click; a click is _press-and-release_ the mouse button) — is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding this handler on only "onclick" event, add this on "onmouseup" and "onmousedown" events

```
<div onmouseup="alfred()" onmousedown="alfred()">Example</div>
```